# Cassandra 3.2 crashing at cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType.compareCustom(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I

Tags: java, cassandra, jvm, timestamp, bytebuffer

Issue:
Cassandra crashing in every 3-4 hrs with:

> # J 8283 C2 org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType.compareCustom(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I (6 bytes) @ 0x00002b7d3d417fb4 [0x00002b7d3d417c80+0x334]

Configuration:

- Xms8G
- Xmx16G
- apache-cassandra-3.2 with Java - 1.8.0_161-b12.

hs_err_pid.log:

```
# Problematic frame:
# J 8283 C2 org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType.compareCustom(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I (6 bytes) @ 0x00002b7d3d417fb4 [0x00002b7d3d417c80+0x334]
```

Has anyone faced similar issues ?

Comment: On the off chance, this is a JVM bug I would try update 181.

Comment: Figured out the issue. CQL queries were not optimized and anti pattern queries were being executed which was causing this. Queries will multiple 500+ partition key values in the IN clause was the root cause.

Comment: This is the sort of error which could only be caused by a bug in the JVM (or a low-level access in Cassandra) While not doing this query might avoid the problem, it shouldn't be possible to construct a query which has this error.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey . We will plan to upgrade Java to 1.8 and will update the thread if this appears again.